# iOS azure push notification application badge

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I am setting `UIUserNotificationTypeBadge` in `UIUserNotificationSettings` but still the **badge** doesn't appear on the app when a notification arrives.
What might be the reason and in that case the solution for this.

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeSound |
                                            UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge categories:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the badge value in your Notification payload.

Here is the sample code that will set the badge to 5.

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "Game Request",
            "body" : "Bob wants to play poker"
        },
        "badge" : 5
}
```

You can learn more about the payload here.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html

Comment: But application badge shall be set outside didRecievePushNotification. This function is called when push notification is opened. Not when it appears. That is in hand of the OS and the notification service api. In this case azure.

Comment: I am getting the badge with this, but it is not incrementing it's value. Suppose the app badge value was previously 1. And new notification arrived. Ideally the app badge value should be 2. But still it is showing 1.

Comment: That has to be managed on server. If you want to show the badge value to be 2 then you will have to send "badge": 2. iOS will show the latest badge you send in the notification payload.